# Reference to all iframes from innermost iframe to topmost iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

By title it means for example:

in a window.top it has iframe1 has iframe2 inside this it has iframe3 and further more it has iframe4

now in document.ready of iframe4 event i need reference to all iframes i.e. iframe4,iframe3,iframe2,iframe1 using jquery.

Can anyone help me out?

Regards

Comment: Should be pretty easy to traverse up by `window.parent` until `window !== window.parent`.

Comment: @dfsq I am new to jquery can you help me out with a sample.